# Ingresar más de una fila a partir de otras tablas

Tags: mysql

Me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar con el siguiente problema:

Tengo tres tablas: Adquisiciones, Bajas y Distribución de bajas. Necesito que al momento de insertar una baja esta me tome una o más filas dependiendo de la cantidad que yo quiero bajar. Por ejemplo, si quiero dar de baja 10 y tengo un registro de cantidad 5 y otro registro de cantidad 5, me tome estas dos y me las ingrese en la tabla Distribución de bajas de manera independiente con su respectivo cálculo.

Les adjunto una foto de cómo sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola felipe, puedes explicarnos un poco más, estoy confundido con el ejemplo... podrías decirnos que sistema quieres implementar

Comment: O sea quieres que ingresando una cantidad, el sistema te elija una o más filas, hasta que la suma de su campo "valor" calce con la cantidad que quieres dar de baja

Comment: @amenadiel  
Es un sistema de gestión de activos fijos, amenadiel claro algo así, pero puede ser mayor o igual y la diferencia me la guarde como saldo. Necesito que me pudieran dar alguna idea o quizás ayudarme con el modelo.

Answer (score 0):

Un sistema como ese no puede funcionar simplemente a nivel de base de datos. No hay una relación *relacional* entre la tabla de adquisiciones y la tabla de bajas que permita señalar que cada registro en la tabla de bajas va mermando la existencia de la correspondiente adquisición.

Pienso que necesitas una capa de lógica de negocios que te tocará programar en tu lenguaje favorito, cosa de manejar tu relación de inventario con una lógica arbitraria.

Al esquema de tu base de datos, yo añadiría en la tabla `ADQUISICIONES` un campo `restantes` que indique cuántas unidades de esa adquisición aún siguen funcionales y no se han dado de baja.

Teniendo ese campo, la lógica del sistema sería (seudo código)

```
function disminuirAdquisicion($id_mesa_reunion, $cantidad) {

    inserto en tabla distrib_de_bajas($id_mesa_reunion, $cantidad);
    actualizo el registro $id_mesa_reunion en la tabla aquisiciones fijando restante=restante-$cantidad;
    return;
}

function darDeBaja($cantidad) {
   // Doy de baja X mesas
   Reviso el primer registro de mi tabla de adquisiciones con restante > 0
   obtengo los valores del ID $id_mesa_reunion y el restante $restante
   if ($restante >= $cantidad) {
      return disminuirAdquisicion($id_mesa_reunion,$cantidad)
   } else {
      // vacío la adquisición 
      disminuirAdquisicion($id_mesa_reunion,$restante)
      // La función se vuelve a llamar a sí misma con el saldo por dar de baja
      return darDeBaja($cantidad-$restante)
   }
}
```

Esta lógica podría hacerse con dos procedimiento almacenados, si te acomoda trabajar con éstos.